# How does a defined variable get set to undefined inside an ajax call via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call to an api which returns successful, however there is a slight issue with a variable that gets set to undefined which I don't get why. I select an `<i>` element and store it inside a variable to display it as a loading bar, and I then try to hide it again inside the success callback.

The element is stored successfully and is used to display the loading bar before the ajax call, however it gives an error saying its undefined inside the success callback. I am perplexed about what could cause the issue. Couldn't find any other solutions online. Please see code below.

The weird thing is I have an `<ul>` element that is declared after the `<i>` element and it never gets set to undefined.

```
$("li.country").on("click", function(){
    var i = $(this).find("i"); //this is where the element is stored
    var cc = $(this).attr("data-city") + $(this).attr("data-country-code");
    var ul_week = $("#week");
    i.toggleClass("no_show"); //works fine here, shows the element
    $.ajax({
      url:        forecast_base_url + cc + units + APPID,
      success:    function(result){
        i.toggleClass("no_show"); //gives an error here
        $("#cc_city").html("This forecast for " + result.city.name + ".");
        ul_week.html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < result.list.length; i++) {
          ul_week.append(
            "<li>Hello World"+ i +"</li>"
          );
        }
        console.log(result);
      },
      error:      function(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: This is unrelated, and in principle it will work, but you are using the variable `i` to do two different things: as jQuery variable, and also as a loop variable. As I said, it will work, but it would better in the long term if you use a different variable name. In particular, I find it useful to give jQuery variables such as this a `$` prefix to make it clear to the rest of the code what type of data it is. Apropos your problem, I think that the problem may be one of scope. I think I have it. Check my answer below.

Comment: Cam answered the question correctly below. I will keep your suggestion on coding convention in mind going forward. The "i" variable is used by the Ajax function as well. Thanks for your input however :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@charlietfl pointed out that the issue is caused by variable hoisting within your ajax callback rather than an issue within jQuery overwriting `i`.

JavaScript doesn't have block scope (except with ES6 `let`), so the `var` declaration within the `for` loop gets hoisted to the top like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url:        forecast_base_url + cc + units + APPID,
  success:    function(result){
    var i = undefined;    // variable i is hoisted up
    i.toggleClass("no_show"); //gives an error here
    $("#cc_city").html("This forecast for " + result.city.name + ".");
    ul_week.html("");
    for ( i = 0; i < result.list.length; i++) {
      ul_week.append(
        "<li>Hello World"+ i +"</li>"
      );
    }
    console.log(result);
  },
```

Comment: `i` in closure shown ( each callback) has no relevance. OP's issue has to do with hoisting

Comment: Update is much more appropriate...I suggest you just delete the rest since it is misleading